# Work of Brauer on Modular Representations

Tags: soft-question, representation-theory

It is well-known that Modular Representation Theory of groups was initiated by Brauer. It has many interesting applications in group theory.

The beginning of representation in any teaching is usually done with introduction to Ordinary representation theory and some classical (many) theorems in it. However, Modular Representation Theory is hardly touched in such courses.

I wanted to read some *papers* of Brauer on modular representation theory which can be understood from knolwdge of ordinary representation theory. However, many of his early papers are in German, and some experts of this area may have idea of contents of his early papers on modular representations. So

> can one suggest *sequence* of his papers (including German and English) which can be read as *beginning of modular representation theory*, with prerequisite as ordinary representation theory?

---

I want to see only papers of Brauer for modular representation theory initially. Later I will consider books and other materials.